# Why are my two javascript class instances not identical?

Tags: javascript, import, equality, es6-class

I have a custom "Enum" class `TableSourceType` (parent class `Enum` is given below):

```
import Enum from './../../components/enum.js';

export default class TableSourceType extends Enum {}

TableSourceType.csv = new TableSourceType('csv');
TableSourceType.sqLite = new TableSourceType('sqLite');
TableSourceType.mySql = new TableSourceType('mySql');
```

Furhtermore, I have "two" object instances `foo` and `baa` and would expect both instances to be identical and the same as `TableSourceType.sqlite`. However, following equality comparisons yield `false`:

```
foo === baa

foo.constructor === baa.constructor
```

If I compare the names of the instances I get `true`:

```
foo.name === baa.name
```

I already checked that I only have a single source code file that contains the class "TableSourceType". That ES6 class is imported with

```
import TableSourceType from '../notebooks/treez/src/data/table/tableSourceType.js'
```

=>Why do I get two different constructors for the "same" import?

Starting from my main html file, I have two `<script type="module">` blocks.

The second script block is added dynamically at runtime in order to inject some user defined code and to save some stuff in a global variable.

The comparison takes place in the first ("static") script block. Maybe that somehow causes the instances not to be identical?

=> How can I ensure equality?
=> Where can I find more information to better understand that equality issue?

Actually I would like to use instances of my custom class in a switch statement:

```
switch (this.sourceType) {
        case TableSourceType.csv:
            this.__showAndHideCompontentsForCsv();
            break;
        case TableSourceType.sqLite:
            this.__showAndHideCompontentsForSqLite();
            break;          
        default:
            var message = 'The TableSourceType "' + this.sourceType + '" is not yet implemented.';
            throw new Error(message);
}
```

That switch statement fails. I would expect `this.sourceType` and `TableSourceType.sqLite` to be equal but they are not.

If it is not possible to ensure equality for instances in different script blocks (?) ... is it possible to implement something like custom "equals" and "hashcode" methods in JavaScript?

If so, I would try to tell TableSourceType to define its equality only based on the name property of the instances.

Here is my custom Enum class:

```
export default class Enum {

    static get values(){
        var keys = Object.keys(this).filter(key=>!key.startsWith('__'));        
        return keys.map(key=>this[key]);
    }   

    static get names(){
        return this.values.map((value)=>value.name);
    }

    static get importLocation(){
        return this.__importLocation;
    }

    static forName(name){
        for(var type of this.values){
            if(type.name === name){
                return type;
            }
        }
        throw new Error('Unknown value "' + name + '"');
    }

    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
        if(!this.constructor.__importLocation){
            this.constructor.__importLocation = this.determineImportLocation();
        }                       
    }

    toString(){
        return this.name;
    }

    determineImportLocation(){
        var stack = new Error().stack;
        var lastLine = stack.split('\n').pop();
        var startIndex = lastLine.indexOf('/src/');
        var endIndex = lastLine.indexOf('.js:') + 3;
        return lastLine.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }

}
```

A work around would be to use the name property in the switch statement:

```
switch (this.sourceType.name) {
        case TableSourceType.csv.name:
            this.__showAndHideCompontentsForCsv();
            break;
        case TableSourceType.sqLite.name:
            this.__showAndHideCompontentsForSqLite();
            break;          
        default:
            var message = 'The TableSourceType "' + this.sourceType + '" is not yet implemented.';
            throw new Error(message);
}
```

However, I would prefer the original version of the switch statement.

Comment: Two variables holding objects are equal only if they are *literally* the same object, as in `a = {}, b = a`. Not if they *look* similar.

Comment: I expect them to be literally the same object! TableSourceType.sqLite should only exist once. So maybe my question could be restated to "Why are they different objects?".

Comment: Under the hood they are never the same object. They are only the same object if you reference them. With the `new` keyword there will always be a new Object.

Comment: Hm. I am getting closer. I expected the new statement to be executed only once because the import already has been resolved before. I just set a break point and in fact it is executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

I expected the content of my custom class file to be executed only once, because the import already has been resolved before. Thanks to Dani R I found out that the code is actually executed twice.

Following adapted code of `TableSourceType` works for me:

```
import Enum from './../../components/enum.js';

export default class TableSourceType extends Enum {}

if(window.TableSourceType){
    TableSourceType = window.TableSourceType;
} else {
    TableSourceType.csv = new TableSourceType('csv');
    TableSourceType.sqLite = new TableSourceType('sqLite');
    TableSourceType.mySql = new TableSourceType('mySql');
    window.TableSourceType = TableSourceType;
}
```

If there is a more elegant way to ensure equality, please let me know.